# User shares a file and enables auto-copy feature that will copy/duplicate the shared file automatically.

Tags: user-behavior

What I want to achieve :

- User shares a file and can authorize an action that will create a duplicate of the file that has been shared with him automatically.
  If this is the existing UI available, what could be
  a quick iteration ?

[image]

This is what I have tried :
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by quick iteration?

Comment: "Quick Iteration" : Not making major changes in the current UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a quick fix, I'd suggest placing the checkbox near the bottom, and providing a help icon that is next to the label to help users understand what the control means.

This avoids the awkward splitting of fields between recipients and the personal message, and places the checkbox in the left-aligned visual flow to help the user perceive it as a next step in the workflow before hitting the share button.

If you want to ensure that the user pays attention to the checkbox, you could also reposition the <kbd>Share</kbd> button under the checkbox, on the left.

[image]